# IO Write errors for sufficiently large files

Tags: r, bash, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, s3fs

I'm working on an EC2 instance with 500 GB RAM, a 500 GB mounted drive used as cache and mounted S3 buckets through s3fs.  I'm trying to merge numerous large (~130 GB) csvs into a single file in the mounted bucket.  No matter what solution I've tried (C, C++, R, bash) after the merged file gets to ~100 GB in size (cache still not full) I get some variant of "Write error: Operation not supported" which typically occurs after 2 or 3 of the smaller files are merged.  I've exhausted my know-how and am not sure how to proceed with these file merges.

Sample code (R):

```
library(data.table)

file1 <- fread('file1.csv', header = True, sep = ',')
fwrite(file1, 'merged.csv', append = True)
so on and so forth ...
```

Bash:

```
cat *.csv >> ../merged.csv
```

Comment: Could the error be related to the used file system (FS)? Some FS have a maximum file size < partition size, however I have never heard of a 100GB limit.

Comment: Yes that's what's odd to me, I don't believe there's any such limitation as I'm able to read files 150+GB in size into memory to process, but for some reason merging these files is very fragile.  At first I thought that maybe bash is too fragile for this which is why I tried more heavy duty options like C++ and R but they all give similar errors which I believe are related to writing into the S3 bucket.

Comment: There is no way to really, properly "mount" a bucket -- there are only hacks, like s3fs and goofys.  How are you doing it?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot good catch, I'm mounting using s3fs.  Edited the original post to reflect that addition.

Comment: iirc, s3fs requires available temp space as large as the file you are creating, to stage the file it is uploading.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot I figured as much which is why I increased the tmp cache size to 500GB.  Recently I ran cat 30gb_file.csv >> 60gb_file.csv with roughly 400GB free of the 500GB cache and it came up with the same "Write error: Operation not supported." Doesn't appear to be any sort of permissions error as I could write up to 60ish GB just fine, however once it gets around that size it starts giving these errors.

Comment: I use s3fs and it works okay as long as you don't run into any of its rough edges... but appending to large files like this may be pushing it.  S3 itself does not have an append operation (objects are immutable once created), so s3fs necessarily must download the entire existing file before it can "append" by creating a new object (iirc, goofys just denies appending altogether, for exactly this reason). Using  `-o dbglevel="debug"` when mounting with s3fs should turn on logging of the low-level operations and perhaps provide something useful in syslog.

Comment: 2021 update: s3fs can now incrementally update objects via server-side copy.  This means that the client machine does not need to download the entire object to make a small update.  It flushes dirty data every 5 GB by default.  However this still incurs significant IO costs on the server.